# heroku h10 error on a project with no backend

Tags: heroku

I'm having trouble deploying a non-backend project to Heroku.
This is a three.js project without any files that contain any server setup or backend handling what so ever.

I know Heroku expects you to handle the backend of your project.

I have followed a guide that supposably resolves this issue with a simple PHP one-line-code.
(guide in the following link)
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-deploy-a-basic-static-html-website-to-heroku/

yet i am still receiving the following error:

```
2022-08-21T15:07:42.323670+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aviv-shleyfman.herokuapp.com request_id=489ae888-d2bf-4e44-ad3e-69571e21d73a fwd="79.177.54.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-21T15:07:43.040882+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aviv-shleyfman.herokuapp.com request_id=3e95892f-9879-42e7-9960-cbff8ed98835 fwd="79.177.54.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-21T15:07:52.543530+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aviv-shleyfman.herokuapp.com request_id=1244f5f5-d0ce-4015-8136-7bf183e15a18 fwd="79.177.54.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-08-21T15:07:52.952393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aviv-shleyfman.herokuapp.com request_id=2de52081-a70f-479f-99d1-2a07ce03c4d7 fwd="79.177.54.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have tried to find a solution online - but I have encountered only suggestions regarding backend problems.

Any suggestions why possibly am I receiving this error?

Comment: If you have no back-end you probably shouldn't be using Heroku. You can shoehorn static hosting into it, as many people do, but it's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Please read [ask]. We're not going to go off-site and read through some questionable tutorial just to understand what you are asking. Please include details of what you did directly in your question.